# OrientDB - Initialization of variables within Gremlin.compile()

Tags: groovy, orientdb, gremlin, orientdb-2.1

http://gremlindocs.spmallette.documentup.com/#shortest-path

Trying to figure out how I could iniitalize a Collection within the Gremlin script scope, while forming a Gremlin Pipe in Java, to optimise the Shortest Path query

```
Pipe pipe;
pipe = Gremlin.compile("s = _() as      Set;_().as('x').bothE().bothV().simplePath().loop('x'){it.loops<=7 }{ !(it.object.id in ['#"+fromId+"','#"+toId+"'])}.path.filter{it.last().TYPE==\""+toType+"\" && it.last().OBJECTREF==\""+toObjectRef+"\"}.path[0]");
pipe.setStarts(new SingleIterator<Vertex>(fromV));
```

Im trying to achieve the following , which is documented in the link above

```
gremlin> s = [root] as Set
==>v[0]
gremlin> target = '99'; c = 0;root.both().except(s).store(s).sideEffect{c++}.loop(4){it.object.id != target && it.loops <= 10}.has('id',target).path().iterate(); c
==>100
```

Any help will be appreciated